# Print only '+' or '-' if string matches (with two conditions)

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to add two additional conditions to the actual code I have: print '+' if in File2 field 5 is greater than 35 and also field 7 is grater than 90.

Code:

```
while read -r line
do
    grep -q "$line" File2.txt && echo "$line +" || echo "$line -"
done < File1.txt '
```

Input file 1:

```
HAPS_0001
HAPS_0002
HAPS_0005
HAPS_0006
HAPS_0007
HAPS_0008
HAPS_0009
HAPS_0010
```

Input file 2 (tab-delimited):

```
Query   DEG_ID  E-value Score   %Identity   %Positive   %Matching_Len
HAPS_0001   protein:plasmid:149679  3.00E-67    645 45  59  91
HAPS_0002   protein:plasmid:139928  4.00E-99    924 34  50  85
HAPS_0005   protein:plasmid:134646  3.00E-98    915 38  55  91
HAPS_0006   protein:plasmid:111988  1.00E-32    345 33  54  86
HAPS_0007   -   -   0   0   0   0
HAPS_0008   -   -   0   0   0   0
HAPS_0009   -   -   0   0   0   0
HAPS_0010   -   -   0   0   0   0
```

Desired output (tab-delimited):

```
HAPS_0001   +
HAPS_0002   -
HAPS_0005   +
HAPS_0006   -
HAPS_0007   -
HAPS_0008   -
HAPS_0009   -
HAPS_0010   -
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} 
NR==FNR {if($5>35 && $7>90) a[$1]++; next}
{print (($1 in a) ? $0 FS "+" : $0 FS "-")}' f2 f1
HAPS_0001       +
HAPS_0002       -
HAPS_0005       +
HAPS_0006       -
HAPS_0007       -
HAPS_0008       -
HAPS_0009       -
HAPS_0010       -
```

Answer (score 1):

```
join file1.txt <( tail -n +2 file2.txt) | awk '
 $2 = ($5 > 35 && $7 > 90)?"+":"-" { print $1, $2 }'
```

You don't care about the second field in the output, so overwrite it with the appropriate sign for the output.